# How can I get a set of changed files from a Phing copyTask?

Tags: php, phing

I use Phing to copy files from a development folder into a live application folder after pulling the latest version of our code. Usually only a handful of PHP-files have been changed.

```xml
<copy verbose="true" todir="${targetpath}" id="copy.source" >
  <fileset dir="${sourcepath}" id="source.files">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

Now I want to get a list of changed files to run integrity checks on them. Ideally this list is available BEFORE the files are copied, but that is not the main issue for now.

Is there a method to get the list of files that have been affected by the copyTask? Than I can run `php -l` on each one of these files.

I don't want to run checks on all files because there are hundreds of files in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

All your copied files have a modified timestamp by todays date.
After the copy you could get a list of all that files (which were modified equals to today) by using the `date` selector.
Something like this will give you a comma separated list of files with a modified date of today.

```xml
<copy verbose="true" todir="${targetpath}" id="copy.source" >
  <fileset dir="${sourcepath}" id="source.files">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
  </fileset>
</copy>
<fileset dir="${targetpath}" id="changed.files">
  <include name="**/*.php" />
  <date datetime="${TODAY}" when="equal"/>
</fileset>
<echo>changed files: ${toString:changed.files}</echo>
```